# Browser access to HP ProCurve 1400-24G

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, hp

My workplace has a HP 1400-24G J9078A switch. I want to connect to it via browser. I tried the manual and other options but could not find any reference.

Comment: Are you unable to reach it at all or are you having difficult logging into it? If you cannot reach it, you will need to plug a console cable into it to see if it has an IP and if so, what VLAN the IP is on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 1400 is a completely unmanaged switch.

There's nothing to connect to with a browser.